# Grouping Set of Points to a Pre Defined Point

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm looking to create a model that classifies a set of points that are near a pre-defined point.

For example, let's say I have points:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 7 |

My goal is to identify which points are closest to predefined point (2,2) and ideally output which points those are.

I tried using KNN, but I could not figure out how to get the KNN model to train results near (2,2). Any guidance to how I may accomplish this would be awesome. :)

[Plot of Points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DZCK.png)

```
df <- data.frame( x = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,6,8,8,9,10), y = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,6,7,5,3,7))
df

goal_point <- c(x=2,y=2)
goal_point
```

Answer (score 1):

You might approach this by calculating distance from goal as a feature.

```
df$dist = sqrt((df$x - goal_point["x"])^2 + 
               (df$y - goal_point["y"])^2)
df$clust = kmeans(df, 2)$cluster

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = clust)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

In this case kmeans is using x, y, and distance from goal. You could also use just distance from goal by using `df$clust = kmeans(df[,3], 2)$cluster`, which would lead here to the same clustering.